# Bevel tool not working properly

Tags: bevel

I'm new to blender and i'm having a problem, the bevel tool is not behaving like i want when i press ctrl+b

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you mixing trianlges and quads?

Comment: Nope, only quads

Comment: Try applying scale, then bevel. To apply scale: ```ctrl``` + ```a```. Then choose ```scale```.

Comment: hard to see what's happening, maybe share the part of the mesh where you try to bevel: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was incorrect normals, I used <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and it solved the problem.